# How come spam user can repost spam?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, spam

User: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4969585/lionel-messi

Posted spam: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620117/1-844-780-6762-outlook-support-phone-number-outlook-tech-suppo @ 12:28 -- suitably flagged and deleted

and then posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622234/1-855-709-2847-canon-printer-customer-care-toll-free-number-canon @ 13:55 -- again deleted

and there may have been ones I didn't personally see.

I know we get a lot of this sort of spam, but that it was the *same user account* surprised me.

Doesn't the system place some sort of block on an account if it was known to be posting spam?

Comment: Well, it's all gone now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single post being flagged and removed for spam isn't enough, though if a moderator comes by it the user would most likely get removed.

I can tell you that the user was blocked following the second spam post.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just surprised at the time difference between the two, so assumed there were more in between I hadn't seen. I've seen these guys reusing accounts before but not with such gaps.

Comment: This. They're usually blocked after the second spam post is _noticed_, but they might have posted 10 more prior to that happening. The first bits of signal the system gets from people is usually sufficient, there's just usually some remaining garbage to clean up if a mod hasn't yet destroyed them.

Comment: We're also seeing an unusual amount of 'snow shoe' spammers, who use botnets to post the same garbage. Same thing applies, individual networks get blocked quickly, but due to the distributed nature of the attack, there are more remnants to deal with, even though the system trained pretty quickly on them.

Comment: @TZHX - these guys do seem to reuse accounts (I've seen them on MSE and other sites), but not if we get to them first ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are many things in place to stop the spammers but these tech support spammers are tricksters who get around a lot of the tools.

If you see it, then flag it as spam.  The account will eventually be destroyed which it has been.